# How to have an additional element that will appear with only some of possible values in an XML schema

Tags: xml, xsd

I want to have the following XML structure:

the element `option` can have one of several values, for some of the values I also want to have an additional element `parameter`, and for some to not have them:

```
<test>
    <option>foo</option>
    <parameter>123</parameter>
</test>
```

**or**

```
<test>
    <option>bar</option>
</test>
```

I tried to do it in the following way:

```
<xsd:element name="test" type="testOptionType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>

<xsd:complexType name="testOptionType">
    <xsd:choice>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="option" type="testOptionWithParameterEnum" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            <xsd:element name="parameter" type="xsd:string" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:element name="option" type="testOptionEnum" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
        </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:choice>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:simpleType name="testOptionWithParameterEnum">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="aaa" />
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:simpleType name="testOptionEnum">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
        <xsd:enumeration value="bbb"/>
    </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>
```

But when I try to validate it I get the error:

> Error For Type 'testOptionType'. Multiple Elements With Name 'option', With Different Types, Appear In The Model Group.

Is there a way to implement what I want in the schema?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to use <choice> from complex types in XSD with 2 values of a same element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59317973/how-to-use-choice-from-complex-types-in-xsd-with-2-values-of-a-same-element)

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems here:

Firstly, your `xs:choice` is ambiguous.

Rather than defining the content model as `choice(sequence(A,B), A)`, define it as `sequence(A, optional(B))`, where `optional B` is expressed using `minOccurs="0"` on the `xs:element` particle.

A choice in XSD must be unambiguous: when the validator, reading the XML top-to-bottom, sees an element, it must know without lookahead which branch of the choice to take, simply by looking at the element name.

Secondly, your content model violates the constraint "element declarations consistent". If two element particles in a content model have the same name then they must also have the same type. There's no way around that in XSD 1.0. In XSD 1.1 you can add additional constraints using assertions, for example (on the declaration of element test)

```
<xs:assert test="if (exists(parameter)) then option='aaa' else option='bbb'"/>
```

Comment: Your solution with `minOccurs="0"` is what I am using temporarily, but it's weaker and allows "aaa" without a parameter. I wanted to have the schema cover it. Now I need to do extra checks to check for this case.

Comment: Yes, as I explained, you'll have to add the extra constraints using `xs:assert`.

Comment: What if tomorrow the number of options that do/don't require `parameter` increases? If it's now `aaa` and `ccc` that require it and `bbb` and `ddd` don't require it, is there a way to expand this in the `xs:assert`?